# undefined reference to std::tuple<std::any, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits, std::allocator > >::tuple<true, true>()

Tags: c++, шаблоны-с++, tuple

Почему этот [код с cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/class_template_argument_deduction) [выдаёт ошибку](https://godbolt.org/z/961Ksr9nr)? Как исправить?

```
#include <tuple>
#include <string>
#include <any>

template<class... Args>
struct B : std::tuple<Args...>, Args... {};
B b{ std::tuple<std::any, std::string>{}, std::any{} };

int main(){}
```

> undefined reference to std::tuple<std::any, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits, std::allocator > >::tuple<true, true>()

Comment: VC++ компилирует и линкует без проблем.

Comment: clang 13 ругается на кучу всего, gcc 11 - не линкует

Comment: Редкий случай, когда вопрос про undefined reference заплюсован.

Comment: Может компилятор не поддерживает c++14?

Comment: да, clang13 и gcc11 очень плохо поддерживают с++14 (режим сарказма выключен)

Comment: @KoVadim, Зачем здесь сарказм? До сих пор никто такую мысль не высказал, хотя в коде применяются особенности c++14. Шутка про 13 и 11 тут странная.

Comment: Статья, на которую ссылается автор вопроса, про CTAD, но в этом коде они не применяются.

Comment: @моя шутка состояла в том, что gcc 11 точно поддерживает 14 стандарт https://gcc.gnu.org/projects/cxx-status.html . Хотя автор использует функции 17-20. по ссылке на cppreference я примера не увидел

Comment: @maestro CTAD применяется при выводе типа переменной `b`, без CTAD пришлось бы писать `B<std::any, std::string>` вместо `B`.

Comment: @KoVadim clang ругается, т.к. у него ещё [поддержка](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/compiler_support) для агрегатной инициализации не реализована. Если добавить типы явно, см. мой коммент выше, то clang сожрёт.

Comment: прикольно. надо пойти освежить в памяти детали.

Answer (score 1):

В данном случае имеет место быть какой-то баг gcc при наследовании от `std::tuple<std::string>` и агрегатной инициализации.

Упрощённый код, который сбоит подобным образом в [gcc 11.1](https://godbolt.org/z/TTsbjEGGo):

```
#include <tuple>
#include <string>

using T = std::tuple<std::string>;

struct B : T {};
B b {T{}};

int main() {}
```

> undefined reference to `std::tuple<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits, std::allocator > >::tuple<void, true>()'

Но запускается нормально на [gcc 10.3](https://godbolt.org/z/deo1nov7r).

Если в вашем примере заменить `std::string` на другой тип, то тоже будет работать [нормально](https://godbolt.org/z/a8Tenacv1).